# Displaying dropdown ul in list

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, hover

I have tried everything but iam stuck on this one. i would like the ul ul li to be shown when hovering the ul li. Anyone who can see what i need to do? I think i'm doing something wrong with the declaration of the ul's and li's but i'm not shure if that's the only problem.

By the way: it's a vertical menu/list

HTML:

```
<!--::::: SIDEBAR :::::-->

    <div class="sidebar"> <!-- sidebar starts-->
        <!-- menu starts-->
        <div id="menu_nav">
          <ul class="main">
             <li class="selected"><a class="selected" href="#featured_work1">Wat is D-day</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Waarom een invasie</a></li>
                   <li class="sub"><a href="#featured_work2">Het doel</a></li>
               <ul >
                <li><a href="#featured_work2">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#featured_work2">test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#featured_work2">test3</a></li>
               </ul>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Operation Fortitude</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work2">Landingsplaats</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Atlantische muur</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work2">Organisatie Todt</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Batterijen</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Luchtlandingen</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work2">Amfibische landingen</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Tijdlijn</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work2">Na D-day</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Cijfers</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">De Facties</a></li>
             <li><a href="#featured_work1">Materiaal</a></li>
             <li class="last"><a href="#featured_work2">Kaarten</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- menu ends -->
```

CSS:

```
/* A) SIDEBAR MENU ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */
#menu_nav { }
#menu_nav ul li { display: block; border-bottom: 1px dashed #555; }

#menu_nav ul ul li { display: block; border-bottom: 0px dashed #555; }

#menu_nav ul ul li a {
    display: none;
    border-bottom: 0px dashed #555;
    padding: 7px 0 0px 58px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: url(style/images/forward_light2.png)  no-repeat;
    background-position: 38px 7px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease; }

#menu_nav ul li.sub a:hover ul { display: block; }

#menu_nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0 11px 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #9b2929;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: url(style/images/arrow-right.png)  no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease; }



#menu_nav ul li.last { border-bottom: 0 solid #444; padding-bottom:10px; }
#menu_nav ul li a.selected { 

    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0 11px 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#252525;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: url(style/images/arrow-right-red.png)  no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 7px;
    }



#menu_nav ul li a:hover {
    padding: 7px 0 11px 45px; 
    -moz-opacity: 0.85;
    -ms-filter:progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85);
    filter: alpha(opacity=85);
    opacity: 0.85;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.85;
    text-decoration: none; }

#menu_nav ul ul li a:hover{
    padding: 7px 0 0px 62px; 

    text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of complicated descendant selectors, which I think is your problem.

First off, delete the `display: none` line right after `#menu_nav ul ul li a`.

Then add these declarations to your CSS:

```
li.sub ul {
display: none;
}

li.sub:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Then, in your HTML, change the following lines:

```
<li class="sub"><a href="#featured_work2">Het doel</a></li>
           <ul >
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test3</a></li>
           </ul>
```

To the following:

```
<li class="sub"><a href="#featured_work2">Het doel</a>
           <ul >
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#featured_work2">test3</a></li>
           </ul></li>
```

In other words, put the `<ul>` *inside* `<li class="sub">`.

That works for me in Chrome 25. Is this what you're after?

**Transitions**

You're somewhat limited with the types of transitions you can do in this scenario. CSS transitions won't work on the `display` rule, and they won't work on `height` unless you use exact sizes (so switching from `height: 0` to `height: auto` will not animate). Using an exact height is pretty tricky, and would immediately break if you ever changed your content. So you've got two options: perform a less-perfect transition on the opacity of the `<ul>` (a fade-in effect), or use jQuery to add a slide-down effect for visitors with JavaScript turned on.

If you change your CSS to this:

```
li.sub ul {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease; 
}

li.sub:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

the space for the `ul` will "pop" into view, then the content will fade in.

Alternatively, you can use jQuery just to add a slideDown effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sub').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
});
```

Then change your CSS rule to this:

```
li.sub ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

(The :hover rules are no longer needed.) That might look more elegant to you. If you choose this route, be sure to create a fallback which "unwrites" the `display:none;` rule for visitors without JavaScript turned on, or they won't see anything!

Comment: Than you very much!!! Maybe a transition would be appropiate. If you could help me with that aswell, that would be great!

Comment: Unfortunately, you're a little limited with the kinds of transitions you can do. If you want a slide-down effect, I think you'd have to resort to jQuery, so users with JavaScript shut off wouldn't see the transition (but would have all the other functionality). Other transitions, like fading in, are possible, but the space for the `<ul>` would "pop" into visibility, and then the content would fade in. I've updated my answer with the two possibilities.